# When I use Sequence to generate table associations, my foreign keys are repeatedly created

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

### This is my code

```
const sequelize = require("./dbConnect");
const Admin = require("./model/adminModel");
const Banner = require("./model/bannerModel");
const Blogs = require("./model/blogsModel");
const BlogType = require("./model/blogtypeModel");
const md5 = require("md5");
(async function () {
  // Set the association relationship of the table

  BlogType.hasMany(Blogs, {
    foreignKey: "categoryId",
    targetKey: "id",
  });
  Blogs.belongsTo(BlogType, {
    foreignKey: "categoryId",
    targetKey: "id",
    as: "category",
  });

  // sync
  await sequelize.sync({
    alter: true,
  });
  const adminNumber = await Admin.count();
  if (!adminNumber) {
    await Admin.create({
      name: "MY,
      loginId: "root",
      loginPwd: md5("123456"),
    });
    console.log("Successful...");
  }
  // 
  const bannerNumber = await Banner.count();
  if (!bannerNumber) {
    await Banner.bulkCreate([
      {
        midImg: "/static/images/bg1_mid.jpg",
        bigImg: "/static/images/bg1_big.jpg",
        title: "Hello",
        description: "nothing",
      },
    ]);
    console.log("OK1...");
  }
  console.log("Over...");
})();
```

The problem lies here
When I am developing a server using Nodejs, the foreign key 'foreign' of the table blogs in my MySQL database will be duplicated

```
BlogType.hasMany(Blogs, {
    foreignKey: "categoryId",
    targetKey: "id",
  });
  Blogs.belongsTo(BlogType, {
    foreignKey: "categoryId",
    targetKey: "id",
    as: "category",
  });
```

The tables in my database are like this, and the names of foreign keys will keep changing when I restart the server

**Table Blogs**

| foreignKey | Various parameters... |
| --- | --- |
| blogs_ibfk_4 | Various parameters... |
| blogs_ibfk_5 | Various parameters... |

[These two images are my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WmJX.png)

[These two images are my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npPmz.png)

Comment: Do you use `sync` to create/alter the DB structure?